# Check for image with same filename but different extension

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, php

I'm using the following code to show images in an ACF Gallery field

```
<?php $images = get_field('gallery'); if( $images ): ?>

<?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>

   <figure class="wp-caption aligncenter">

          <img class="b-lazy" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/images/spinner.gif" data-src="<?php echo $image['sizes']['featured-720']; ?>" alt="<?php the_title();?>">

   </figure>

<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

What i would like to do is to check for each $image, if there is another attached image with the same filename but different file extension (png).

For example:

There is an image attached called "ThisTitle.jpg" and I want to check if there is also another image attached called "ThisTitle.png"

I hope this make sense :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [pathinfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) and [getimagesize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php):

```
$info = pathinfo($image);

if ( @getimagesize($info['dirname'] . '/' . $info['filename'] . '.' . $extension_to_check) )
{
    // do something
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I don't know if i'm doing anything wrong, i just get this error: "Warning: pathinfo() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in"

Comment: @user2093301 I think the error is very clear. I suggest to change `$image` to `$image['sizes']['featured-720']` in your case.

Comment: i think we are really close. I've change the code a bit to this: $info = pathinfo($image['sizes']['featured-720']); if ( getimagesize($info['dirname'] . '/' . $info['filename'] . '.jpg') ) { echo 'Exists'; } Now, if the image exists, it echoes the message, if not it gives the following error: Warning: getimagesize(domain/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/374/4_158602_2W1260.jpg): failed to open stream

Comment: @user2093301 We can use `@` prefix to bypass that error, e.g `@getimagesize(...)`. Note that if you only want to check against images inside your local folders, I recommend to use [file_exits()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.file-exists.php) as it's much more efficient in compare to `getimagesize()`.